# How to specify remote config URL when running Telegraf in docker container

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I am running telegraf in a docker container. I want it to load remote configuration via http url (from influxdb telegraf configurations).

I know that there is --config commandline option but how do I do this when running telegraf in a docker container of via docker compose file?

Is there a way to specify the config file url via an environment URL?

Answer (score 0):

You should override `CMD` instruction from original dockerfile. Adding `command: telegraf --config <influx_url>` to docker-compose did the trick for me.